# Use validation error values on custom Joi/celebrate messages

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, joi

I'm creating something using a nodejs/typescript stack for the server, and I'm trying to define custom generic error messages instead of per-field messages. Something like this:

```
routes.post(
    '/points',
    upload.single('image'), 
    celebrate({
        body: Joi.object().keys({
            name: Joi.string().required(),
            email: Joi.string().required().email(),
            whatsapp: Joi.number().required(),
            latitude: Joi.number().not(0).required(),
            longitude: Joi.number().not(0).required(),
            city: Joi.string().required(),
            uf: Joi.string().required().max(2),
            items: Joi.string().required()
        }),
    }, {
        abortEarly: false,      
        messages: {
            'string.empty':'{context.label} cant be empty!'
        }
    }),
    pointsController.create
);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use a variable/value inside the custom message. I got that 'key' based on the error entry that comes out of celebrate/joi error, which is like this:

```
{
  message: ' cant be empty!',
  path: [ 'items' ],
  type: 'string.empty',
  context: { label: 'items', value: '', key: 'items' }
}
```

If there a way to do something like that?
The message is not 'parsing' the {context.label} as I though it would. I mean, this is a shot in the dark since I couldn't find anywhere if something like this is suported at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{#label}` to achieve what you want to.

Try:

```
.messages({
  'string.empty': '{#label} cant be empty!',
  'any.required': '{#label} is a required field for this operation'
})
```

and so on for all other types.

Other values are also accessible similarly. For ex, if you want to generalise the error message for string min/max:

```
.messages({
  'string.min': '{#label} should have a minimum length of {#limit}'
})
```

Here, limit (min) was set when you created the schema for the string.

Comment: Ohhhh, so that's how I get them! Do you have a documentation link for that? (so I can find more stuff)

Comment: Sure. Joi's github documentation provides some understanding of this: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#template-syntax. To get more familiar, read more on the same page.